# How can I scroll to a specific element while scrolling down to a page?

Tags: jquery

While loading the page initially, It will scroll to the bottom of the page 
and loads next set of elements and if found the element 16 then scroll to bottom of the page and again scrolls back to element 16.
How can I directly scroll to element 16?

Element 16 comes only when scrolling down the page.

Scroll to the element 16,

```
if($("#16").length === 0){ 
    clearScroll = setInterval(function(){ 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 
    $(document).height()-$(window).height()});
    if($("#16").length !== 0){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 
        $('#16').parent().offset().top - 100}, 'slow');
        clearInterval(clearScroll); 
    }
 }, 1000); 
 }
 });
```

Scrolls to element 16 only when first scrolls to page bottom after that it scrolls to element 16 that is present in the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.... You can chain `animation` which execute after first `animation` completed.

```
if($("#16").length === 0){ 
    clearScroll = setInterval(function(){ 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 
    $(document).height()-$(window).height()});
    if($("#16").length !== 0){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 
        $(document).height()-$(window).height()}).animate({scrollTop: 
        $('#16').parent().offset().top - 100}, 'slow');
        clearInterval(clearScroll); 
    }
 }, 1000); 
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate your try. I tried your logic but it also scrolls to page bottom after that it scrolls to element 16 that is present in the top.